# Finite Element Delphi library

Tags: delphi, finite-element-analysis

Can someone point to me where I can find Finite Element Delphi library.

Preferably opensource.

Comment: I'd be tempted to look into the Python numeric and symbolic computation libraries (sympy, sfepy), which include Finite Element and Algebraic modules that would be easily loaded via a Python extension to Delphi (load Python.dll from Delphi). As Dean says, Pascal isn't usually commonly used by the numerical methods haxxors these days. Check this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCLab

Comment: @WarrenP Well, I sell a finite element tool that is 100% Delphi!! But you are right, it's an extreme niche.

Comment: Okay, Menjaraz, you gotta buy David's thing. :-) Go team Stack Overflow.

Comment: @WarrenP Sadly not viable. Menjaraz is looking for a library, but we offer an FE package.

Comment: Yeah, thought so... still, it's kind of Nifty. :-)

Comment: I've downloaded ORCINA's brochure and handed it to few acquaintances (civil engineers who did little Pascal during their graduation, mostly Fortran people and almost out of practice). I've boasted that all the soft were written in Delphi: I can tell really, they were amazed at.

Comment: @menjaraz thanks! It's clear that we are almost alone in the world doing fem in delphi. We started on turbo pascal and then had a few years on modula-2. 32 bit windows brought back to delphi. We like being able to do GUI work and native number crunching all in the same language. Not only is it productive I think it results in a better, more tightly integrated product.

Comment: @David Heffernan: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never tried, no releases, but source code is available: http://oofem.codeplex.com/
However, this CodePlex project appears to require the [MtxVec math library](http://www.dewresearch.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=137%3Amtxvec-v4&catid=54%3Aproducts&Itemid=79) from [Dew Research](http://www.dewresearch.com/) which is not open source or free. (Note the 'uses MTxVec' in the source code).

**Edit:**

I accepted the answer: It's sofar the only advanced opensource Delphi I come accross.

To share my other findings, I suggest the following french resources (in academia):

- [Méthode des éléments finis: programmes écrits en Pascal](http://iut.univ-lemans.fr/ydlogi/rdm_pascal.html) (source code samples in Delphi).
- [RDM 6.17](http://iut.univ-lemans.fr/ydlogi/rdm_version_6.html) (Binary distribution only).

Comment: The moral: the opensource community must provide SMID capabilities to the 'legacy' standard linear algebra package available from www.netlib.org to keep up.

Comment: Stefano Tommesani's [Extensia](http://www.tommesani.com/Exentia.html) project deserves the Delphi community attention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any that exist anymore since the heyday of Pascal being used for numerical methods work in the 80's.  You best bet is to look into the C++ or FORTRAN projects listed at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries and either convert the code or link to the binaries.  If you can use a commercial library, the NAG library has a write up on using Delphi with their DLLs at: http://www.nag.com/numeric/BorlandDelphi.asp.

You can also try [here](http://bnmc.caltech.edu/resources/finite_element), scroll down to 'Free/Open Source/Shareware Packages' - lots listed, but language is not specifed.

Comment: Wasn't all that NAG Fortran stuff open source some time ago?  I mean, like in the early 90s and late 80s?

Comment: [CALCULIX](http://www.calculix.de/) is indeed a good package. I've harnessed it in the past, unfortunately it's not in Delphi. I highly recommend it.